# What's Easy in F# That's Hard in C#?

Tags: c#, f#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In what areas might the use of F# be more appropriate than C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785029/in-what-areas-might-the-use-of-f-be-more-appropriate-than-c)

I'm anticipating giving a presentation at the local .Net user group about F#.  And I'm anticipating the "Why should I look into F#?" question from the audience.  I know most of the stuff that can be done in F# can be done in C# too--so I'm looking for things that can be done easily in F# that are really hard to do in C# (e. g. pattern matching).  And if there are already good answers to this question, please just link them in comments and I'll close this up. I did see a few things but if there's already a question that addresses this I didn't find it.

By the way, if any of the moderators want to mark this community wiki please feel free; this seems more like a survey question to me anyway.

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close this because it sounds subjective and/or argumentative. But I'm not 100% sure about that.

Comment: @Bobby, as I say, if someone wants to mark this community wiki that's fine with me.  I realize this is sort of a survey question but I can't mark the question community wiki myself.

Comment: (just a side note: a lot of times I've seen this question compare good F# to bad C#, i.e. Not using appropriate C# devices; I'm not saying there aren't differences - but be aware of that gotcha; note also how C# 5 (the async CTP) improves the threading powers of C# with continuations etc)

Comment: @Bobby, I'm still relatively new to stackoverflow, and appreciate the goal of avoiding questions that get transformed into jihads. I think this question solicits opinions that don't require argument. I look forward to seeing the answers to this. Is there another another forum that is more appropriate for a question like this?

Comment: @delnan--Thanks for the links. My google fu must be failing me.  I'll close this question since I believe it is a dupe. (Edit): Hmm...thought as the person who posed the question I'd be able to automatically close it.  Guess I was wrong.

Comment: @Cos Callis: Not on SE as far as I can see. This is a Q&A network and all sites are trying to avoid possible subjective and argumentative questions or the kind which can be turned into a discussion. But most of the time the wording makes a big difference, as in this example.

Comment: Voting to reopen. I'd answer the alleged duplicate question with generic application domains (e.g. "heavily concurrent server applications" or "programmatically-generated GUIs") whereas I'd answer this with specific code samples (e.g. some mutually recursive asynchronous workflows implementing a state machine in an elegant way that relies upon tail call elimination, or a parser written as a set of mutually-recursive active patterns, or a simple concurrent program doing message passing using a `MailboxProcessor`).

Comment: IMMUTABILITY! It's a huge pain in C#. Here's a simple--yet painful--example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172510/should-i-choose-f-to-develop-a-distributed-server-platform/5172903#5172903

Comment: I think there are plenty of questions that already cover this topic. Just look at the list of the highly voted F# questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23?sort=votes&pagesize=50

Comment: @Tomas: I don't think that is a constructive response. In particular, I don't see any questions with answers like the ones I described above. You might as well just tell the questioner to master F# himself using all available information and then answer his own question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of a main concept is asyncrounus calls in F#, also F# uses immutable variables so concurrency is easy.

see http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=147194
and http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=79947 and other [Don Syme](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/dsyme/) articles. may be there are other differences, but I think gathering them here is just doing your homework.

Comment: In particular, the *Async* functionalities in F# are production-level quality, while the Asnyc functionalities of C# (and VB.NET) are still in CTP phase.

Comment: And tail call elimination makes async far more elegant in F# anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Since F# is a functional language, it should be far easier to implement a domain-specific language in it.

Answer (score 2):

i would say

- Asynchronous programming.
- Units of measure

Comment: Units of Measure is nice, but it is a hack much like Java generics (erasure), meaning no reflection, no use outside of the assembly.