# In what ways does F# shine? (Cool real-world examples of its added value)

Tags: c#, .net, f#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the benefits of using C# vs F# or F# vs c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952318/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-c-vs-f-or-f-vs-c)

I’ve done a bit of reading about F# and I am starting to see a push for it at my place of employment.

Where is it that F# really shines to a degree which would cause a C# developer to break out of the normal humdrum of problem solving and utilize F#?

Please, give me your best snippet - I need something to run with.

Comment: Would be a great question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Repeat question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952318/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-c-vs-f-or-f-vs-c although this does not have snippets.

Comment: @Caimen: If its a repeat, I'll delete it - but I'm not asking for a differential breakdown between C# and F#.

Comment: It's funny that the guys who closed it appear to have never answered an F# question. Maybe they just like closing questions. Sorry, NTDLS.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks! Now I can move on knowing that at least someone agrees. :D

Comment: @NTDLS: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5172510/162396) may help you some too.

Comment: look at ironjs - this is a javascript runtine written in F#. Very impressive as a real-world sample of F#. I intend to grok this code big time

Comment: @pm100: Holy sh*t, that's crazy. I didn't even know that was possible. I sure am glad I duplicated this question.

Comment: For some nice F# snippets, you can also check out http://fssnip.net :-)

Comment: One word - REPL. Okay, one abbreviation :)

Comment: +1 and vote for reopen. The alleged duplicate asks for prose whereas this question asks for code.

Comment: Jon: Whether it's a duplicate or not, it doesn't fit StackOverflow Q&A format.  Way too open-ended.